# How to set filter to off as default in devexpress grid

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

I have a devexpress grid and I have the filter working per column, but how to make the filter be not display but only upon user request (default would be off or false.)

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="gvPBMCharges" ClientInstanceName="gvPBMCharges"                                
                            runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  Width="1100px"  KeyFieldName="FACILITY_ID"
                            SettingsBehavior-AllowGroup="true" SettingsPager-PageSize="20" DataSourceID="SDSPBMDashboard">
                            <Settings ShowFilterRow="true" ShowFilterRowMenu="true" ShowGroupPanel="True" ShowFooter="True" />
                            <SettingsPager>
                                <PageSizeItemSettings Visible="true" Items="10, 20, 50" />
                            </SettingsPager>
```

Comment: Are you talking about the autofilter row?

Comment: yes that is, each col offers the filter of the data. we would like the default to be off and user has to select to have this fitler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the `ShowFilterRow` property to `false`:

```
<dx:ASPxGridView (...)>
    <!-- other stuff -->
    <Settings ShowFilterRow="false" (...)/>
    <!-- other stuff -->
</dx:ASPxGridView>
```

In fact you also can just forget about setting the attribute at all, since by default it's `false`. See the [online documentation](https://help.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridViewSettings_ShowFilterRowtopic) for reference.

If you want it shown on user request just set the property to `true` on whatever event you want.